# Finding out the velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

> Displacement of an object is related to time $x=at+bt^2-ct^3$ where a, b and c are constant motion.Then the velocity of an object when it's acceleration is zero is given by
>
> 1. $a+\frac{b^2}{c}$
> 2. $a+\frac{b^2}{2c}$
> 3. $a+\frac{b^2}{3c}$
> 4. $a+\frac{b^2}{4c}$

I have done the following things:

$\frac{d}{dt}tx=a\frac{d}{dt}t+2b\frac{d}{dt}t^2-c\frac{d}{dt}t^3$

$\ v=a+2bt-3ct^2$

After this I am stuck I don't know how to move ahead can anyone help me?

Comment: BTW, for the last term, it will be 3ct^2

Comment: I think when any user ask the homework question, he should mention his effort in solving it and where he had problem. That what i have done i have written the question, shown my effort in solving the question and also mentioned where i was stuck. Then why was it put on hold. **[This](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8975/simple-harmonic-motion-problem)** was the question i had found in the [meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) in which user had asked the question almost in the same format as mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$v=\frac{dx}{dt}=a+2bt-3ct^2$$
$$acc=\frac{dv}{dt}=2b-6ct=0$$
This gives
$$t=b/3c$$
Put this in $v$ to get the answer

$$v=a+\frac{b^2}{3c}$$

Comment: LOL I was avoiding giving him all the steps and have him do some of it himself :P

Comment: @Gummybears +1 to you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way, when the acceleration is zero, the velocity is constant. Thus:

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = 0$$

Find $t$ in terms of $b$ and $c$
After doing so, substitue them into the equation you found for velocity, and it will give you the answer. I got:

$$a + \frac{b^2}{3c}$$